# Photoshop Shine Effect

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photo-editing

I work with Photoshop and there's one effect I've seen that I can't manage to copy. The effect I'm looking for is the shiny effect in the next image:

[image: Shine Effect]

I looked online for shine effects but they never look like this one, usually they are made by lens flare but it's just not the same.

Thanks ahead :)

Comment: Well, do you want to learn to make the effect by your own or do you want to know which add on can do this effect? In both cases I can't help you. BTW: welcome to GD.SE!

Answer (score 3):

a dot of white, blur > motion blur horizontal. duplicate this layer and transform it wider and shorter and layer until it has a nice natural look, merge all together. duplicate, rotate 90 degrees, merge. duplicate layer, rotate 45 degrees, transform 60%, center. white blurry dots in the center at increasing size (decrease opacity for each). merge (or dont), light gaus blur, outer glow white

E: had to duplicate and transform the original 'line' 2 or 3 times in varying width and height.

the trick is creating a few original white dots and motion blurring them different amounts and then transforming the results so when you center them all and layer they have a natural feathered look but still are opaque enough.

here's the super lazy result:
[image]